# How can I execute something only if the function has been called once in the past 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `zoomed` that executes anytime a user zooms in on part of the screen.  So it can execute several times in a matter of seconds as the user zooms.  I want to log 'done zooming' the last time the function is called.  What is the best way to achieve this?

```
function zoomed() {
  console.log('called');
  // If this has only been called once in past
  // 5 seconds, user is done zooming
  // console.log('done zooming')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work:

```
var doneZooming = true; //Global variable to store the current "state" of zooming
var zoomTimeout = null; //Variable to store our 5-second timer

function zoomed() {
   resetZoomTimer();
   console.log("zooming");
}

function resetZoomTimer() {
   doneZooming = false;
   clearTimeout(zoomTimeout); //End current timer
   zoomTimeout = setTimeout(zoomComplete, 5000); //Reset the timer to 5 seconds
}

function zoomComplete() {
   doneZooming = true;
   console.log("zooming complete");
}
```

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/L8zo8hfy/) is an example of this code in use. Keep an eye on console.

---

The `zoomComplete()` function acts as a callback that will fire when the user is finished zooming.

If this isn't necessary, you can probably eliminate some of the functions here - I broke it out for readability. On that same note, you could simply move the functions within `resetZoomTimer()` into your `zoomed()` function if you're looking to consolidate, but again, personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is commonly called *debouncing*. It's used regularly in scenarios like yours.

It's not hard to write the function yourself, but utility libraries like lodash have good implementations.

```
widget.on('zoom', _.debounce(zoomed, 5000, { trailing: true }));
```

What this does is start listening when zooming happens, then after a 5 second pause in zooming, call the `zoomed()` function.

See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

Answer (score 0):

I would personally have a global variable (accessible by all instances of the function) that is assigned a setTimeout function at the end of the function execution. This creates a timer that would only execute if it wasn't cleared by another instance of the function.

e.g.

```
var zoomTimer;

function zoomed() {
    console.log('called');
    // Clears the timeout associated with the variable
    clearTimeout(zoomTimer);
    // Sets the 5 second timeout
    zoomTimer = setTimeout(function() { console.log('done zooming'); }, 5000);
};
```